# What the available templates/frameworks for developing single page applications using visual studio / .net?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, single-page-application

We are developing a single page application / web site. We started off with visual studio / ASP/C# as our development platform. While the initial application was more of a Proof of concept and did not have much of an "architecture" - we want to structure this better and use some frameworks already available. What are the frameworks available in Visual Studio 2012 for developing single page applications, and what are the pros and cons of using each?

TIA

Answer (score -1):

This might be a useful place to look.

http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/introduction/other-libraries

Comment: If you have an answer, please actually answer the question, rather than just linking to an external source. Remember, only *you* can prevent blogspam.